# Ruby regex what does the \1 mean for gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

What does the \1 do?

For example

```
"foo bar bag".gsub(/(bar)/,'car\1')
```

I believe it has something to do with how you use parentheses, but I'm not really sure.  Could someone explain it to me? And can you do stuff like \2?  If so, what would that do?

Comment: want to repeat group(1) another time. use \1 and () represents group

Answer (score 28):

Each item that you surround with parenthesis in the searching part will correspond to a number `\1`, `\2`, etc., in the substitution part.

In your example, there's only one item surrounded by parenthesis, the `"(bar)"` item, so anywhere you put a `\1` is where the part inside the parenthesis, will be swapped in. You can put in the `\1` multiple times, which is handy if you want to repeat that found item, so you could legitimately write `car\1\1\1` and `"bar"` will be swapped in three times.

There's no use for `\2` because there's only one item surrounded by parentheses. However, if you had `(bar)(jar)`, then the `\1` would represent `"bar"` and `\2` would represent `"jar"`.

You could even do things like this:

```
\1\2\1\2\2\1
```

which would become:

```
barjarbarjarjarbar
```

Here's a real-world example where this comes in handy. Let's say you have a name list like this:

```
Jones, Tom  
Smith, Alan  
Smith, Dave  
Wilson, Bud
```

and you want to change it to this:

```
Tom Jones  
Alan Smith  
Dave Smith  
Bud Wilson
```

You could search for:

```
(.+), (.+)
```

and replace with:

```
\2 \1
```

You could also replace with:

```
\1: \2 \1
```

Which would become:

```
Jones: Tom Jones  
Smith: Alan Smith  
Smith: Dave Smith  
Wilson: Bud Wilson
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your answer better. Stack Overflow has [a nice help system](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that describes how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that helped. I cleaned it up.

Comment: Take a look at how I formatted it by clicking on the "edited" link above my edit notice.

Comment: That does look nicer. Are you using the backticks inline to format the code that way in the first 3 paragraphs? I thought that code had to be on a separate line to get the grey highlight look. Thanks for helping me get up to speed on this; still pretty new on SO.

Comment: It's all covered in the online help when writing questions or answers.

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking `\N` is replaced with the N-th group specified in the regular expression. The first matched group is referenced by `\1` and the maximum number of groups is 9.

Some examples:

```
# wrap every integer into brackets
'1 2 34'.gsub(/(\d+)/, '[\1]')
# => "[1] [2] [34]"

# gsub with two groups: swap couples of integers
'<1,2> <3,4>'.gsub(/(\d+),(\d+)/, '\2,\1')
# => "<2,1> <4,3>" 

# you can reference the same group more than once
'1 2 34'.gsub(/(\d+)/, '<\1,\1>')
#  => "<1,1> <2,2> <34,34>"

# a slightly more complex example
'Jim Morrison'.sub(/([A-Z])[a-z]+ ([A-Z][a-z]+)/, '\2 \1.')
# => "Morrison J."
```

Answer (score 6):

The `\1` is syntax for the last capture in a regular expression using the `()` like you said.  It says whatever was matched, replace it with that.

You can continually use `()` groups and their respective `\2` to continue to replace what you matched.

Comment: Can you do \2?  Where/how would you use that?

Comment: @Tommy Sure, you just need to have another group.  This site is excellent for regular expression questions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html.

Comment: In case you ever have (nested (groups)) note that the numbers refer to the order of *opening* parentheses