# Splitting a string without delimiters in R

Tags: regex, string, r, split

I have a character vector in `R`, with each element containing a string - let's use this example:

```
my.files <- c("AWCallibration#NoneBino-3", "AWExperiment1#NoneBino-1", "AWExperiment2#NonemonL-2"
)
```

I would like to extract certain information out of these strings -

1. First, two uppercase alpha characters (in this case, always `"AW"`)
2. Whether the trial was for calibration (`"Callibration"`) or data collection - if it was the latter, which condition was used (`"Experiment1"` or `"Experiment2"`)
3. Which sub-condition was used on this particular trial (`"Bino"` or `"monL"`)
4. The repetition of the sub-condition (`"1"` or `"2"`)

I first tried using `strsplit`, but this only appears to work for cases with **regular** delimiters such as `"_"`. `substring` appeared to suit my needs better, but did not actually work due to the fact that splits don't occur in regular places (`"Experiment1"` is eleven elements long, `"Callibration"` is twelve).

I suspect that use of regular expressions may be the answer here, but I don't know how to account for the different lengths between the splits.

Comment: Use `substring`, it is vectorised and will work on all elements at once. And yes, you will need multiple conditions and multiple substring invocations

Comment: `substr` still has the same problem as `substring` - how to account for splits that do not occur at the same element each time?

Comment: You do not have to make all the decisions in one single condition and in one single line, do you? (Hint: use nested `ifelse` in the else condition if you want to collapse your conditions into one line :)

Comment: You are correct! I just have the bug of trying to make everything as compact as possible (often to my detriment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the information one by one:

```
first <- substr(my.files, 1, 2)
# [1] "AW" "AW" "AW"

second <- sub("^..(.*)#.*", "\\1", my.files)
# [1] "Callibration" "Experiment1"  "Experiment2" 

third <- sub("^.*#None(.*)-\\d+$", "\\1", my.files)
# [1] "Bino" "Bino" "monL"

fourth <- sub(".*-(\\d+)$", "\\1", my.files)
# [1] "3" "1" "2"
```

---

**All in one command:**

```
strsplit(my.files, "(?<=^..)(?=[A-Z])|#None|-", perl = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "AW"           "Callibration" "Bino"         "3"           
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "AW"          "Experiment1" "Bino"        "1"          
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "AW"          "Experiment2" "monL"        "2"
```

Comment: This is a perfect step-by-step guide, much thanks. Now to put my head down and go through the regex - it's a good learning exercise.

Comment: @luser Regular expressions are a very powerful tool. Learning will be worth it.

Comment: I'm being dense - how does `sub("^..(.*)#.*", "\\1", my.files)` produce "Callibration" et al? 


From what I can tell, the regex specifies a pattern that is essentially the entire string - two characters, plus any number of characters up until the hash, then any number of characters after that until the end of the string.


`sub` then appears to replace the string with another - "\\1". Am I reading the second part of the `sub' parameters wrong?

Comment: @luser You're right. `"\\1"` means that the whole string is replaced by the part of the string inside the first parentheses `"()"`. In this case, it's everything after the second character up to (but not including) the `"#"` sign.

Comment: That is ingenious... to my inexperienced mind anyway. The clarification was much appreciated. May I ask how `"\\1"` specifies the part of the string inside the parentheses as I haven't seen examples of this in the documentation for `sub`?

Comment: @luser Have a look at this question for the meaning of `\1`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825872/ruby-regex-what-does-the-1-mean-for-gsub By the way: I added an additional solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few different solutions:

**gsubfn::strapplyc** Try this:

```
library(gsubfn)
pat <- "(..)(.*)#None(.*)-(.*)"
strapplyc(my.files, pat, simplify = rbind)
```

which gives:

```
     [,1] [,2]           [,3]   [,4]
[1,] "AW" "Callibration" "Bino" "3" 
[2,] "AW" "Experiment1"  "Bino" "1" 
[3,] "AW" "Experiment2"  "monL" "2"
```

*Note* that in the development version of the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) there is a `read.pattern` command which could use the above `pat` like this:  `read.pattern(text = my.files, pattern = pat, as.is = TRUE)` .

**sub/strsplit** Here is an alternate solution.  It inserts a minus after the second character and then splits each strip by minus or `#None`:

```
my.files2 <- sub("(..)", "\\1-", my.files)
do.call(rbind, strsplit(my.files2, "-|#None"))
```

which gives:

```
     [,1] [,2]           [,3]   [,4]
[1,] "AW" "Callibration" "Bino" "3" 
[2,] "AW" "Experiment1"  "Bino" "1" 
[3,] "AW" "Experiment2"  "monL" "2"
```

**gsub/read.table**  Here we use `gsub` to insert a minus after the first two characters and also we replace `#None` with minus.  Then we use `read.table` with a `sep` of minus to read it in:

```
withMinus <- gsub("^(..)|#None", "\\1-", my.files)
read.table(text = withMinus, sep = "-", as.is = TRUE)

  V1           V2   V3 V4
1 AW Callibration Bino  3
2 AW  Experiment1 Bino  1
3 AW  Experiment2 monL  2
```

*REVISION:*

- A correction and a second solution.
- Third solution.

Comment: This is a very nice collection of alternative solutions, which also satisfies my inexplicable need for everything to be done in as few lines as possible.